# Combining XMLAGG and REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

Problem: Have free-form text fields with some  (U+000B) characters that end up appearing in the text and causing some errors in my SQL extracts when I use XMLAGG:

```
ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed.
```

I was attempting to write-in a REGEXP_REPLACE code to remove these characters that keep appearing but I'm struggling to get it to complete. When I run the REGEXP_REPLACE code I've written to test on a confirmed row of data with this problem, it runs:

```
select PARENT_REQUEST_ID,
REGEXP_REPLACE(worklog_details,'\s{2,}', '') as inbound_call_notes
from ARADMIN.FTS_WORKLOG

where worklog_type is not null AND
parent_request_id ='000000001234567'
```

Below is the full SQL script I've been trying to work the REGEXP_REPLACE into:

```
SELECT 
ti.CUSTOMER_ID as CID,
ti.billing_id as BID,
ti.TROUBLE_ID,
ti.REPORTED_BY,
ti.DISPATCHED,
to_char(to_date('01-JAN-1970','dd-mon-yyyy')+((ti.create_date/60/60-7)/24), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') as createday,
to_char(to_date('01-JAN-1970','dd-mon-yyyy')+((ti.create_date/60/60-7)/24), 'YY-MM') as createmo,
to_char(to_date('01-JAN-1970','dd-mon-yyyy')+((ti.date_closed/60/60-7)/24), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') as closeday,
to_char(to_date('01-JAN-1970','dd-mon-yyyy')+((ti.date_closed/60/60-7)/24), 'YY-MM') as closemo,
ti.CATEGORY1 as CAT1,
ti.CATEGORY2 as CAT2,
ti.CATEGORY3 as CAT3,
inbound_call_notes,
ti.RESOLUTION_CODE1 as RES1,
ti.RESOLUTION_CODE2 as RES2,
ti.RESOLUTION_CODE3 as RES3

FROM
aradmin.fts_ticket ti
LEFT JOIN (select PARENT_REQUEST_ID,
rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,worklog_details,', ').extract('//text()') order by PARENT_REQUEST_ID).getclobval(),', ') as inbound_call_notes
  from ARADMIN.FTS_WORKLOG
  where worklog_type is not null
  GROUP BY PARENT_REQUEST_ID) wk ON wk.PARENT_REQUEST_ID = ti.TROUBLE_ID

WHERE
ti.trouble_id IN ('000000001234567')
```

Is it a matter of putting the REGEXP_REPLACE before rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement)) or do I need to go about this a little bit differently? This is some newer territory I'm venturing into, so my experience is limited.

Comment: Hi - what does “struggling to get it to complete” mean? When you run that minimal SQL does it error or does it run? If it errors, what error?  If it runs then what does it do that isn’t what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The small SQL does run on it's own with no errors.

What I'm hoping to achieve is REGEXP_REPLACE filters out the unicode symbols  and then in the same query XMLAGG would combine all the rows into a single value. When I added the REGEXP_REPLACE portion to my larger query I get the following error: 

ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out how to integrate REGEXP_REPLACE properly with a coworker yesterday. Here is what I did:

```
FROM
aradmin.fts_ticket ti
  LEFT JOIN (select PARENT_REQUEST_ID,
  rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(x,REGEXP_REPLACE(worklog_details, '[^[:print:]]', ''),', ').extract('//text()') order by PARENT_REQUEST_ID).getclobval(),', ') as inbound_call_notes
  from ARADMIN.FTS_WORKLOG
  where worklog_type is not null
  GROUP BY PARENT_REQUEST_ID) wk ON wk.PARENT_REQUEST_ID = ti.TROUBLE_ID
```